# How can i get a pc name of user connected via diffrent networks to my application

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

Presently i am in intranet.I have connected to **SERVER -A** from my laptop and from there i was logIn to one php application running on another server(**SERVER-B**) which exists in same intranet. My need is i want to get the PC name of the user from php application which is running on **SERVER-B**. 
When i use **$pcname = gethostnamebyaddr($_server['REMOTE_ADDR']);**
i am getting **SERVER-A host name**,but i want **laptop Computer NAME**,how can i get this?

Comment: I want to login directly to my php application with that username

Comment: var network=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
 alert(network.UserName);                                                                                        
   this code is working in IE browser , i want same implementation in chrome

Answer (score 0):

this depends on your router... its possible you could do a ptr dns request for it manually to your router

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup